CUPS - remote shared printers can only print plaintext or PDF, not PNG
I'm managing a warehouse with some printers. The way it works is that one raspberry pi computer (B) is hooked up via USB to a few printers. Then, a central one (A) sends on print jobs via printer sharing to the others. It all works fine with PDFs. But for some reason, .PNGs fail! (also other image formats like .jpg) Some logs from /var/log/cups/error_log:
A:
I [29/Aug/2024:17:42:41 +0100] [Job 422879] Queued on "zebra_7" by "root".
D [29/Aug/2024:17:42:41 +0100] [Job 422879] Auto-typing file...
D [29/Aug/2024:17:42:41 +0100] [Job 422879] Request file type is image/png.
I [29/Aug/2024:17:42:41 +0100] [Job 422879] File of type image/png queued by "root".
D [29/Aug/2024:17:42:42 +0100] [Job 422879] 2 filters for job:
D [29/Aug/2024:17:42:42 +0100] [Job 422879] - (image/png to printer/zebra_7/image/png, cost 0)
D [29/Aug/2024:17:42:42 +0100] [Job 422879] - (printer/zebra_7/image/png to printer/zebra_7, cost 0)
D [29/Aug/2024:17:42:42 +0100] [Job 422879] envp[29]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=image/png"
D [29/Aug/2024:17:42:42 +0100] [Job 422879] Setting the device uri to  ipps://zebra_7%20%40%20yellow-raspberry._ipps._tcp.local/cups
D [29/Aug/2024:17:42:42 +0100] [Job 422879] Printer supports output formats: pdf
D [29/Aug/2024:17:42:42 +0100] [Job 422879] Using following CUPS filter chain to convert input data to the PDF format: gziptoany
D [29/Aug/2024:17:42:42 +0100] [Job 422879] gziptoany (PID 20509) started.
D [29/Aug/2024:17:42:42 +0100] [Job 422879] Set job-printer-state-message to "gziptoany (PID 20509) started.", current level=INFO
D [29/Aug/2024:17:42:42 +0100] [Job 422879] gziptoany (PID 20509) exited with no errors.
D [29/Aug/2024:17:42:42 +0100] [Job 422879] Set job-printer-state-message to "gziptoany (PID 20509) exited with no errors.", current level=INFO
D [29/Aug/2024:17:42:42 +0100] [Job 422879] The filtered output of pdftoippprinter is written to file /var/spool/cups/tmp/0501b66d1258d

looking at /var/spool/cups/tmp/0501b66d1258d with file shows that it is a PNG - I don't know if that's expected or not.
B:
D [29/Aug/2024:17:42:42 +0100] [Job 20] OUTFORMAT=\"<none>\", so output format will be CUPS/PWG Raster
D [29/Aug/2024:17:42:42 +0100] [Job 20] pdftopdf: Last filter determined by the PPD: rastertolabel; FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE: application/vnd.cups-raster => pdftopdf will not log pages in page_log.
W [29/Aug/2024:17:42:42 +0100] [Job 20] /var/spool/cups/d00020-001: can\'t find PDF header
D [29/Aug/2024:17:42:42 +0100] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [29/Aug/2024:17:42:42 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [29/Aug/2024:17:42:42 +0100] [Job 20] Set job-printer-state-message to "/var/spool/cups/d00020-001: can\'t find PDF header", current level=WARN
W [29/Aug/2024:17:42:42 +0100] [Job 20] /var/spool/cups/d00020-001: file is damaged
D [29/Aug/2024:17:42:42 +0100] [Job 20] Set job-printer-state-message to "/var/spool/cups/d00020-001: file is damaged", current level=WARN
W [29/Aug/2024:17:42:42 +0100] [Job 20] /var/spool/cups/d00020-001: can\'t find startxref
E [29/Aug/2024:17:42:42 +0100] [Job 20] loadFilename failed: /var/spool/cups/d00020-001: unable to find trailer dictionary while recovering damaged file

Questions:

It looks like CUPS on A doesn't think B can handle anything other than PDF - why?
Also looks like the conversion to PDF fails - can this be fixed somehow?

I'd really appreciate any help!

Edit your question to show what brand/model printer is being accessed per log files. No experience w CUPS, but I seem to recall that back in the Unix days, there was a separate O'Reilly pub book just about Unix printing (including CUPS). .... Printer supports output formats: pdf . This seems like it must be a setup parameter for printer that you'll have to find how to change. (Seems impossible that a printer could only print pdfs).

I didn't want to complicate the question with too many details. The main thing here is that the USB printers on B (zebra GK420d) can print PNG, JPG, PDF, etc perfectly fine. But somehow that is lost when they are shared via CUPS on B. (So the printers themselves aren't really the problem here I think)

OK, I missed that point /-: .... I really see this as an admin problem, and as this does seem to be about a production system, I recommend you delete here and repost to [sf]. My point about the O'Reilly printer book, was that printing in unix (anyway) is complicated; it won't "Just work" . Don't know enough about the rest of your system to know if you should expect that it should "just work". Ideas:  1) you can spend some of your reputation points and put a bounty on  your Q. ....


note the low number of followers for the tags you have included. Expert readers often only look at questions tagged with technologies where they can can gain more rep points.  3) It's not cheating to add a [unix] or [linux] tag (only one!) as appropriate. .... In summary: the only reason I saw your question is because  I look at the complete feed to be exposed to *nix topics beyond my expertise (see my StackOverflow profile).

